# Determining all workers are done

Tags: go, threadpool

Following [Marcio's thread pool implementation](http://marcio.io/2015/07/handling-1-million-requests-per-minute-with-golang/) is it possible to determine when all work is done?

Waiting for the JobQueue to empty is trivial:

```
// Wait for the job queue to clear
for len(JobQueue) > 0 {
    // Just wait
}
```

However after that there might still be goroutines waiting for workers, or workers have not unfinished all tasks:

```
func (d *Dispatcher) dispatch() {
    for {
        select {
        case job := <-JobQueue:
            // a job request has been received
            go func(job Job) {
                // try to obtain a worker job channel that is available.
                // this will block until a worker is idle
                jobChannel := <-d.WorkerPool

                // dispatch the job to the worker job channel
                jobChannel <- job
            }(job)
        }
    }
}
```

What's the best approach to this? Add a WaitGroup to the dispatcher, and a method for querying the status of the WaitGroup? Any pointers towards this would be appreciated.

Comment: You can't really query the status of a waitgroup, you just wait for the group to be finished. But yes, this is the precise use case for a waitgroup.

Comment: @Adrian Please feel free to write an answer so I can gratify you with virtual points? :) (Just outline how this should be implemented?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per [the documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup):

> A WaitGroup waits for a collection of goroutines to finish.

So, yes, to wait for a collection of goroutines to finish, I would recommend a `WaitGroup`. As the docs state, you call `Add` for each worker started, and `Done` when each worker finishes. Your `for len()` busy loop would be replaced with:

```
wg.Wait()
```

As per the documentation.